# Display difference between 2 timestamps

Tags: grafana, grafana-dashboard

I'm using PostgreSQL as Grafana's data source. In my database I have a record which contains JSON data:

```json
{"start": "1695668520", "end": "1695810577"}
```

In my dashboard which is set as `Stat` I have 2 queries to get `start` and `end` values:

```sql
SELECT info->>'start' AS start_value
FROM public.metrics
WHERE PR = $PR;
```

and

```sql
SELECT info->>'end' AS end_value
FROM public.metrics
WHERE PR = $PR;
```

I've added transformation: *Convert field type* - both to numeric and *Add field from calculation* - Binary operation -> end_value - start_value -> alias: result.
I thought `result` will be displayed in my dashboard, but it's not. I tried to add *Overrides* -> *Field with name*, but the `result` variable/field is not visible there. Am I doing something wrong? I just want to display in my dashboard only the result of these timestamps.

Comment: Why would you do it in Grafana? Doing such operations in the query seems easier: no hustle with Transformations and a single query.

Comment: Good question tbh, doing this operation in Grafana was my first though

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if some operation can be (easily) done on data source's side - it should be. Grafana's transformation can do some staff, but they are not as good as SQL for example.